# How to establish communication/pass data between two ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm aware this question has already been asked numerous times, and I've read many answers referring to it. Nevertheless, none of them fulfilled my requirements, and hence I need some advice.

The application I'm developing at the current moment looks like this:
http://screenshooter.net/100101493/smrkpog

It's a WPF MVVM application based on MVVM Light Toolkit. The area with a grid is a `ListBox` + `Canvas`. The items (let's call them 'Neumes') consist again of a `ListBox` + `Canvas` each and are dynamically created by a user. Every Neume is composed of 'Elements' which are rendered as the red shapes.

When the user double-clicks a Neume, a new window opens. It is supposed to enable editing (translate, resize, rotate) of the Elements the selected Neume is made of. **What I'd like to do** is to pass my SelectedNeume (with a list of Elements) stored in my MainViewModel to the ViewModel of my newly created window. **I have a few ideas on how to achieve this**:

1. Skip the new ViewModel entirely and set MainViewModel as the `DataContext` of the new window,
2. Create a 'MainViewModel' field in the new ViewModel and pass it there when a new window is opened,
3. Use Messaging/Mediator pattern provided by MVVM Light Toolkit.

I'm looking for a solution that is both simple and neat. I'd be most happy to make use of option 3., but I'm a relative newbie as far as WPF is concerned, and don't know how to start really. Also, I'm afraid there might be a problem with the fact that the new window is opened when a double-click event on the main ListBox is fired, since I couldn't find a way to bind a command to the ListBoxItem neither in its Style nor DataTemplate (the event trigger/EventToCommand solution didn't work for me).

This is the event:

```
    private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Neume;
        if (item != null)
        {
            var view2 = new EditWindow();
            view2.Owner = this;
            view2.SetDataContext();
            view2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

The `SetDataContext()` method currently takes care of binding the DataContext according to the 1. option:

```
public void SetDataContext()
    {
        if(this.Owner != null)
            DataContext = this.Owner.DataContext;
    }
```

**My question is**: Which option would you recommend? Are there any problems with either 1. or 2.? Possible memory leaks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would go with option 3.

The messaging mechanism keeps your viewmodels separated from each other and once you work through one example, you'll see it is quite easy.

Personally I like to add a message broker class with static methods for each message type I want to send, this helps me centralise changes - but essentially you've got a send and receive. You can send what you want and if something wants to receive it they can.

MVVM Light is a great framework for this.

Send:

```
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Send<LoginSuccessMessage>(new LoginSuccessMessage() { UserName = user });
```

Receive, in my target View Model constructor:

```
this.MessengerInstance.Register<LoginSuccessMessage>(this, this.OnLoginSuccessMessage);
```

Handler in the target View Model:

```
    private async void OnLoginSuccessMessage(LoginSuccessMessage message)
    {
        this.CurrentUserName = message.UserName;
        this.MoveToState(ApplicationViewModelState.Active);

        await Task.Delay(5000);
        this.MoveToState(ApplicationViewModelState.Idle);
    }
```

In this example, I am sending a user ID as a property on the message class:

```
public class LoginSuccessMessage : MessageBase
{

    private string _UserName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._UserName;
        }

        set
        {
            this._UserName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Replace that property with whatever you want be that a collection or complex object.

Comment: That's what I call a stalker :)

Comment: Stalkers can be friendly too ;)

Comment: This still works? I'm having difficulties implementing